# I want to show two items on 0 position of recyclerview as gridviewlayout in an android application

Tags: java, android

[Top two items in recylerview  is not in same size i want to set them in same size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwwl4.png)

I want to show two items on 0 position of recycled view as grid view layout in an android application and this is what I tried-

```
private void initViews() {
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);

            // Create a custom SpanSizeLookup where the first item spans both columns
            layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    return position == 0 ? 2 : 1;
                }
            });




            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            ArrayList<modelProduct> products = prepareData();
            final DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), products);


            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Comment: First of all read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please explain what your question is

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic:-

Since you want to show 3 items in one row, two items in first row:

 No need to explain ;)

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 6);

 // Create a custom SpanSizeLookup where the first item spans both columns
 layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? 3 : 2;
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer:  i want to show the two items with same size as 1:1 on  0 position but it is looks like this  with your code.